# Retrieving last months data when last month is also last year?

Tags: sql

I have the following Where clause in several queries.  This successfully retrieves the past months data.  Now the year has changed, the query can't find any data (December 2018 hasn't happened yet!).  How can I change the Where clause to overcome this?

```
select *
from somedatabase a
WHERE DATEPART(m, a.meetDate) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
  and DATEPART(yyyy, a.meetDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, getdate())
```

Many thanks and any assistance very gratefully received.

Comment: _somedatabase_ is a poor _table_ name.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Your query is using product specific functions.)

Answer (score 1):

My normal way of rounding down to the start of the current month is:

- `DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0)`

  - Find out how many *whole* months there have been since date 0
  - Then add that many months to date 0
  - Always gives the start of the month *(as date 0 is the start of a month)*
  - Is not affected by leap year, year boundaries, months of various length, etc

This then allows me to do things like...

```
WHERE
      a.meetDate >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()) - 1, 0)  -- start of last month
  AND a.meetDate <  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate())    , 0)  -- start of this month
```

By having the calculations on the right hand side you make maximum use of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
WHERE DATEPART(month, a.meetDate) = DATEPART(month, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate())) AND
      DATEPART(year, a.meetDate) = DATEPART(year, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
```

That is, subtract one month for both comparisons.

Actually, a simpler way is to use the strange rules of `DATE_DIFF()`:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(month, a.meetDate, getdate()) = 1
```

Neither of these can make use of an index.  For that, the expression is a little more complicated:

```
WHERE a.meetDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()),
                                  MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()),
                                  1) AND
      a.meetDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() as DATE))
```